# php not working inside html code in wampserver

Tags: php, wamp

Here's the thing.. I have a file named first.php containing the following code:

```
<html>
    <title>trial</title>
    <head>welcome</head>
    <body>
    <br>
    <?php
    echo "hello world";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

However when I execute it, the php code is not interpreted. The short open tag also seems to be on. I'm using wampserver. what have I missed?

Comment: `<head>welcome</head>` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: What directory is your file in?

Comment: its inside c:/wamp/www/

Comment: I believe you need to move it into your c:/wamp/www/htdocs folder. Then in your browser you should be able to go to http://localhost/yourfile.php

Comment: @SamHuckaby That is not correct Sam. It is however a good idea to create subfolders under the www folder for your projects, eg www/project1, www.project2 etc. Do not use the www folder, it belongs to wamp

Comment: i don't have that htdocs folder. should i create it and then place it there and run it?

Comment: You don't have to call it htdocs, you can call it whatever you want, @RiggsFolly is right, I've been using Unix so long, I guess I had forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <title>trial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try it with the title wrapped inside the head like it should be. The welcome was just floating around in no mans land, may have broken your code. Also, use a doctype tag - `< !html>` without the space is HTML5.

**Update** 
Add this to a blank php file in your localhost folder.

```
<?php
// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
?>
```

If you don't get a report back, it's a server config problem.

*Also make sure your putting it in `htdocs` or whatever your "public" folder is.*

Comment: Also, make sure your address is `http://localhost/yourfolder/yourfile.php`, not just opening the file from the file system.

Comment: Oops,my bad. you were right. I was just opening it from the file system. Now it worked. Ha.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

It seems your server is misconfigured. Your apache server must recognize .php files as a php application and evaluate the code.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

See if you find the line above in your http.conf file.

Comment: is it httpd.conf or http.conf?

Comment: i have two files named like that. in which one should i add it? where should i add it? should it be preceded by #?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you place the `.php` file(s) under a directory say "myfirst" under `/wamp/www`
2. make sure the wamp server is online (shows green icon)
3. Enable short tags click on `wamp icon > PHP > PHP Settings > short open tags`. Make sure it is checked.
4. run the code in browser as `localhost/myfirst/first.php`

hopefully it works

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes suggested by @kcdwayne.

Now run the code from your browser, DONT doubleclick on your php file from explorer, it has to run through a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The  Tag must be inside the  Tag

```
<head> 
   <title>trial</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
</body>
```