# php not working inside html tags

Tags: php, android, json, wampserver

When I am using php code its working fine but when I am using inside html tags its not working, and i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288018/php-not-working-inside-html-code-in-wampserver) solution but didn't worked for me.

Additional summary (I am creating android app which connect android with php mysql, using `utf8` thats why I have to use html tags which supports **(meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8")**

**My Class**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.androidhive.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener,
OnFocusChangeListener {
    private Button mBSpace, mBdone, mBack, mBChange, mNum, xQ1, xW1, xE1, xQ2, xW2, xE2;
    private RelativeLayout mLayout, mKLayout;
    private boolean isEdit = false, isEdit1 = false, isEdit2 = false;
    private String mUpper = "upper", mLower = "lower";
    private int w, mWindowWidth;
    private String sL[] = { "ا", "ب", "پ", "ت", "ٹ", "ث", "ج", "چ", "ح", "خ",
            "د", "ڈ", "ذ", "ر", "ڑ", "ز", "ژ", "س", "ش", "ص", "ض", "ط", "ظ",
            "ع", "غ", "ف", "ق", "ک", "گ", "ل", "م", "ن" };
    private String cL[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
            "X", "Y", "Z", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â§", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â ", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¨", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â»", "ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â®" };
    private String nS[] = { "!", ")", "'", "#", "3", "$", "%", "&", "8", "*",
            "?", "/", "+", "-", "9", "0", "1", "4", "@", "5", "7", "(", "2",
            "\"", "6", "_", "=", "]", "[", "<", ">", "|" };
    private Button mB[] = new Button[32];
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.4:81/android_connect/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

        setKeys();
        setFrow();
        setSrow();
        setTrow();
        setForow();

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        inputName.setOnTouchListener(this);
        inputPrice.setOnTouchListener(this);
        inputDesc.setOnTouchListener(this);
        inputName.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        inputPrice.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        inputDesc.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        inputName.setOnClickListener(this);
        inputPrice.setOnClickListener(this);
        inputDesc.setOnClickListener(this);

        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xK1);
        mKLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xKeyBoard);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), e.toString());
    }
        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);



        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == inputName && hasFocus == true) {
            isEdit = true;
            isEdit1 = false;
            isEdit2 = false;

        } else if (v == inputPrice && hasFocus == true) {
            isEdit = false;
            isEdit1 = true;
            isEdit2 = false;


    } else if (v == inputDesc && hasFocus == true) {
        isEdit = false;
        isEdit1 = false;
        isEdit2 = true;

    }

    }
    private void addText(View v) {
        if (isEdit == true) {
            String b = "";
            b = (String) v.getTag();
            if (b != null) {
                // adding text in Edittext
                inputName.append(b);

            }
        }
        if (isEdit1 == true) {
            String b = "";
            b = (String) v.getTag();
            if (b != null) {
                // adding text in Edittext
                inputPrice.append(b);
            }
            }
            if (isEdit1 == true) {
                String b = "";
                b = (String) v.getTag();
                if (b != null) {
                    // adding text in Edittext
                    inputDesc.append(b);

        }


    }}
    private void isBack(View v) {
        if (isEdit == true) {
            CharSequence cc = inputName.getText();
            if (cc != null && cc.length() > 0) {
                {
                    inputName.setText("");
                    inputName.append(cc.subSequence(0, cc.length() - 1));
                }

            }
        }
        if (isEdit1 == true) {
            CharSequence cc = inputPrice.getText();
            if (cc != null && cc.length() > 0) {
                {
                    inputPrice.setText("");
                    inputDesc.append(cc.subSequence(0, cc.length() - 1));
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    private void changeSmallLetters() {
        mBChange.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        for (int i = 0; i < sL.length; i++)
            mB[i].setText(sL[i]);
        mNum.setTag("12#");
    }
    private void changeSmallTags() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sL.length; i++)
            mB[i].setTag(sL[i]);
        mBChange.setTag("lower");
        mNum.setTag("num");
    }
    private void changeCapitalLetters() {
        mBChange.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        for (int i = 0; i < cL.length; i++)
            mB[i].setText(cL[i]);
        mBChange.setTag("upper");
        mNum.setText("12#");

    }

    private void changeCapitalTags() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cL.length; i++)
            mB[i].setTag(cL[i]);
        mNum.setTag("num");

    }

    private void changeSyNuLetters() {

        for (int i = 0; i < nS.length; i++)
            mB[i].setText(nS[i]);
        mNum.setText("ABC");
    }

    private void changeSyNuTags() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nS.length; i++)
            mB[i].setTag(nS[i]);
        mNum.setTag("ABC");
    }
    // enabling customized keyboard
        private void enableKeyboard() {

            mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
            mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

        }

        // Disable customized keyboard
        private void disableKeyboard() {
            mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
            mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);

        }

        private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        }

        private void setFrow() {
            w = (mWindowWidth / 13);
            w = w - 15;
            mB[16].setWidth(w);
            mB[22].setWidth(w + 3);
            mB[4].setWidth(w);
            mB[17].setWidth(w);
            mB[19].setWidth(w);
            mB[24].setWidth(w);
            mB[20].setWidth(w);
            mB[8].setWidth(w);
            mB[14].setWidth(w);
            mB[15].setWidth(w);
            mB[16].setHeight(50);
            mB[22].setHeight(50);
            mB[4].setHeight(50);
            mB[17].setHeight(50);
            mB[19].setHeight(50);
            mB[24].setHeight(50);
            mB[20].setHeight(50);
            mB[8].setHeight(50);
            mB[14].setHeight(50);
            mB[15].setHeight(50);

        }

        private void setSrow() {
            w = (mWindowWidth / 10);
            mB[0].setWidth(w);
            mB[18].setWidth(w);
            mB[3].setWidth(w);
            mB[5].setWidth(w);
            mB[6].setWidth(w);
            mB[7].setWidth(w);
            mB[26].setWidth(w);
            mB[9].setWidth(w);
            mB[10].setWidth(w);
            mB[11].setWidth(w);
            mB[26].setWidth(w);

            mB[0].setHeight(50);
            mB[18].setHeight(50);
            mB[3].setHeight(50);
            mB[5].setHeight(50);
            mB[6].setHeight(50);
            mB[7].setHeight(50);
            mB[9].setHeight(50);
            mB[10].setHeight(50);
            mB[11].setHeight(50);
            mB[26].setHeight(50);
        }

        private void setTrow() {
            w = (mWindowWidth / 12);
            mB[25].setWidth(w);
            mB[23].setWidth(w);
            mB[2].setWidth(w);
            mB[21].setWidth(w);
            mB[1].setWidth(w);
            mB[13].setWidth(w);
            mB[12].setWidth(w);
            mB[27].setWidth(w);
            mB[28].setWidth(w);
            mBack.setWidth(w);

            mB[25].setHeight(50);
            mB[23].setHeight(50);
            mB[2].setHeight(50);
            mB[21].setHeight(50);
            mB[1].setHeight(50);
            mB[13].setHeight(50);
            mB[12].setHeight(50);
            mB[27].setHeight(50);
            mB[28].setHeight(50);
            mBack.setHeight(50);

        }

        private void setForow() {
            w = (mWindowWidth / 10);
            mBSpace.setWidth(w * 4);
            mBSpace.setHeight(50);
            mB[29].setWidth(w);
            mB[29].setHeight(50);

            mB[30].setWidth(w);
            mB[30].setHeight(50);

            mB[31].setHeight(50);
            mB[31].setWidth(w);
            mBdone.setWidth(w + (w / 1));
            mBdone.setHeight(50);

        }

        private void setKeys() {
            mWindowWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); // getting
            // window
            // height
            // getting ids from xml files
            mB[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xA);
            mB[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xB);
            mB[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xC);
            mB[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xD);
            mB[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xE);
            mB[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xF);
            mB[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xG);
            mB[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xH);
            mB[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xI);
            mB[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xJ);
            mB[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xK);
            mB[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xL);
            mB[12] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xM);
            mB[13] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xN);
            mB[14] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xO);
            mB[15] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xP);
            mB[16] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xQ);
            mB[17] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xR);
            mB[18] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS);
            mB[19] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xT);
            mB[20] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xU);
            mB[21] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xV);
            mB[22] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xW);
            mB[23] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xX);
            mB[24] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xY);
            mB[25] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xZ);
            mB[26] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS1);
            mB[27] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS2);
            mB[28] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS3);
            mB[29] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS4);
            mB[30] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS5);
            mB[31] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xS6);
            xQ1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xQ1);
            xQ2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xQ2);
            xE1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xE1);
            xE2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xE2);
            xW1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xW1);
            xW2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xW2);
            mBSpace = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xSpace);
            mBdone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xDone);
            mBChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xChange);
            mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xBack);
            mNum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xNum);
            for (int i = 0; i < mB.length; i++)
                mB[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            xQ1.setOnClickListener(this);
            xQ2.setOnClickListener(this);
            xE1.setOnClickListener(this);
            xE2.setOnClickListener(this);
            xW1.setOnClickListener(this);
            xW2.setOnClickListener(this);
            mBSpace.setOnClickListener(this);
            mBdone.setOnClickListener(this);
            mBack.setOnClickListener(this);
            mBChange.setOnClickListener(this);
            mNum.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v == mBChange) {

            if (mBChange.getTag().equals(mUpper)) {
                changeSmallLetters();
                changeSmallTags();
                xQ1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                xQ2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                xW1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                xW2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                xE1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                xE2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else if (mBChange.getTag().equals(mLower)) {
                changeCapitalLetters();
                changeCapitalTags();
                xQ1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xQ2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        } else if (v != mBdone && v != mBack && v != mBChange && v != mNum) {
            addText(v);

        } else if (v == mBdone) {
            disableKeyboard();


        } else if (v == mBack) {
            isBack(v);
        } else if (v == mNum) {
            String nTag = (String) mNum.getTag();
            if (nTag.equals("num")) {
                changeSyNuLetters();
                changeSyNuTags();
                mBChange.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                xQ1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xQ2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            if (nTag.equals("ABC")) {
                changeCapitalLetters();
                changeCapitalTags();

                xQ1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xQ2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xW2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                xE2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (v == inputName) {
            hideDefaultKeyboard();
            enableKeyboard();

        }

        if (v == inputPrice) {
            hideDefaultKeyboard();
            enableKeyboard();

        }

        if (v == inputDesc) {
            hideDefaultKeyboard();
            enableKeyboard();

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**<----------------------------->**

**without html tags working fine with android**

```
 <?php

    /*
     * Following code will create a new product row
     * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
     */

    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];

        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

**inside Html tags**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title> Create Product </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Log Cat**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3p8kifm0kpzjsg/Untitled2.png?dl=0

```
04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821): Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41782898 that was originally added here

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41782898 that was originally added here

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
```

Comment: my file is in .php format

Comment: What is the filename and how are you accessing it (What is the URL in the browser)?

Comment: yes @Jonathon it is in url browser like this "http://192.168.1.4:81/android_connect/create_product.php";

Comment: It looks like there is no form to submit so the PHP code may well be being registered by the $_POST has never been set. Do you ever see the json encoded response?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Is there an error, or what? And if you inspect the source of the HTML page, do you see the PHP code there?

Comment: file name is create_product.php

Comment: You are seeing somewhere  `"Required field(s) is missing"` ? Very good. Then all is working! Use any browser to see it.

Comment: @JeroenNoten actually i am inserting my text with android phone which stored in wampserver and its working fine when em not using html tags in my create_product.php file but when em using this html tags my android app crashes and it returns me back to main screen

Comment: @greenapps yes its working in browser with html tags but not in my android app

Comment: Well ok. That has nothing to do with php not working within html tags but with your Android code instead. You should post your Android code and the logcat with the errors and exceptions.

Comment: @Coderrrr yes its a form and its working fine with no html tags but i have to use html tags because of UTF-8

Comment: @greenapps edited my question, you can see my log cat

Comment: You should post your Android code here. Also you should post a relevant part (with the exceptions and functions) in a separate code block here. I will not look in your Dropbox.

Comment: @greenapps  04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821): Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41782898 that was originally added here

Comment: 04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41782898 that was originally added here

Comment: 04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)

04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)

Comment: @greenapps 04-13 17:00:46.512: E/WindowManager(24821): Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41782898 that was originally added here

Comment: Please post yur logcat in your post in an extra block. Not in comments. Now they are unreadable.

Comment: @greenapps question edited with log cat

Comment: That is not the relevant part from the logcat. And you will not show your relevant Android code from the androidhive example? Which good reasons do you have?

Comment: Sorry but i will not look in your Android code either. It is insane to dump so much code. You should post only a little piece of relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

use this at the top of your HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Sunil means that the file must have the extension .php

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see your code but i think the following happens: The php only code delivers a json text. That is what the json parser expects as reply. But now you send a html page. So the json parser will deliver null. You are not checking for `null` so your app will crash with a `NullPointerException`.